# Multiple ASP.NET Identity authentications in single web site

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, asp.net-identity, identity

I'm currently building a new ASP.NET MVC 5 project with a private section dedicated for administrators.
This section is developed in a modular way and have its own authentication (using ASP.NET identity)
I also want a restricted section for customers in the same web site with a different authentication (using ASP.NET identity too).

Is it possible to have different User.Identity objects depending on the location of the website ?
(ex: "ClientUser" at the root of the website and "ExtranetUser" if we go to /Extranet)

Here's the code I currently have for both sections :

Client section (main ASP.NET application) :

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                CookieName = "ClientCookie",
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/LoginRegister"),
                ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(4),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider()
            });
        }
```

Extranet section (stored in the module project) :

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                CookieName = "ExtranetCookie",
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Extranet/Account/Login"),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider()
            });
        }
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can have several `DbContext` (or `IdentityDbContext`) elements in your application. The problem is that during startup you need to provide a database and UserManager as of `CreatePerOwinContext`. Event this can be handled as shown in [this post](http://www.jamessturtevant.com/posts/ASPNET-Identity-Custom-Database-and-OWIN/).

Define your two User and SignIn manager classes:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

    // Add our custom managers
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<CustomUserManager>(CustomUserManager.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<CustomSignInManager>(CustomSignInManager.Create);
}
```

And refer in the corresponding controllers the correct implementation:

```
private CustomSignInManager _signInManager;
public CustomSignInManager CustomSignInManager
{
    get
    {
        return _signInManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<CustomSignInManager>();
    }
    private set { _signInManager = value; }
}
```

I didn't try by myself but the approch looks smart.

Comment: I already have 2 UserManager and SignInManager in my application , but once a user is logged with one of those 2 SignInManager, 
how to get the right information in the IPrincipal object (User) depending on the section of the website (root or /Extranet) ?

Comment: You can sign in a user with `CustomSignInManager.SignIn(customUser);` or `ApplicationSignInManager.SignIn(applicatonUser)`. I would suggest to use Claims to authenticate (see http://bitoftech.net/2015/03/31/asp-net-web-api-claims-authorization-with-asp-net-identity-2-1/) as an example. You could add a claim describing which type of authorization a user has and use [Roles("")] checks at the controller side.

Comment: Can you state some of your application needs for two separate Identity mechanisms. It will help to understand better why you cant use one Identity with Roles and Claims.